# os.rename not working in python

Tags: python

I get an error when I excute below python code:

```
    #!/comm/python/stable/bin/python

import re
import os
import shutil

DestDir="/home/SVModels/"
vamsList="/home/vamsList.txt"

with open(vamsList) as f:
    for line in f:
        fileObj= re.split (r'(/)', line)
        OldfileName=fileObj[-1]
        NewfileName=".".join([fileObj[14], "sv"])
        shutil.copy(line.rstrip(), DestDir)
        print("OldfileName= {}NewfileName= {}".format(OldfileName, NewfileName))
        os.chdir(DestDir)
        print "Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd()
        os.rename(OldfileName,NewfileName)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ConvertVamsToSV.py", line 20, in <module>
    os.rename(OldfileName,NewfileName)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Looks lie os.rename is not able to replace "OldfileName" with string. When I actually change os.rename command to hard quote "OldfileName" then it works.
e.g.     os.rename("myfile.vams",NewfileName)

Any idea why the original code not working?

Comment: What do you think `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` means?

Comment: Have you printed `OldfileName` to make sure it's what you expect?

Comment: have you tried printing `repr(OldfileName)` to see if there are any unseen characters in it? **It probably ends with a newline** as it's the last thing in the line from a file.

Comment: You may want to change the `print` to `print("OldfileName={!r} NewfileName={!r}"...` the `!r` will quote and escape the string so you can be sure exactly what the string contains.  This might not give you any useful information, but it might.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks, you were spot on. I used .rstrip to get rid of \n and it works now!